# Modify TCP Packets with a Java Proxy

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, proxy

For my project I'm trying to modify a OpenFlow Packet, in fact it is a TCP Packet. I want to modify it with a Proxy Server in Java, but i have not found any good solution in the internet. One Source wrote it is not possible to modify the packet with a normal Java Proxy. I am now in the situation that i have no idea how to do it. Do you know any good solution?

thx in advance for your help

Comment: What this sounds like: "I need to know how to inject packets into a connection so I can do something heinous."

Comment: It is for my University Project. Since OpenFlow is relative new there are no real attacks. The task is now to find a point to attack to fix it in newer versions or over some defense mechanisms. I have an idea but i am not sure how to code it.

Comment: Do you mean TCP *segments*? You certainly can't modify those in pure Java. You can't even see them. All you can see is the payload, as a byte stream. No segments, no packets, no TCP headers, no IP headers.

Comment: Yeah I mean the TCP segments. I think it won't be a problem, just to see a byte stream because I know which byte i have to modify.